# terraform v0.12.12 passing data between modules - How Is This Supposed To Work?

Tags: module, output, terraform

I'm struggling to understand the way data is passed in and out of modules in Terraform (v0.12.12). I have what I think is a very simple example, but can't understand how data is supposed to pass between modules. And most of the examples I can find are either incomplete or out-of-date.

I've created a simple example with two modules. A network module that creates a vpc and a subnet, and a compute module that creates an EC2 instance. I'm simply trying to provide the compute module with the id of the subnet where the EC2 instance should go. But I don't understand:

1. how do I get the subnet_id out of the network module that creates
       the subnet to other modules can use it?
2. How do I get the compute module to use the subnet_id ?

The basic structure is as follows

`.
├── main.tf
└── modules
    ├── compute
    │   └── main.tf
    └── network
        ├── main.tf
        └── output.tf`

```
# main.tf
provider "aws" {
    region     = "eu-west-1"
}

module "m_network" {
    source      = "./modules/network"
}

# The problem is how to make that subnet id available to the compute module
# so the ec2 instance can be added to it? 
module "m_compute" {
    source     = "./modules/compute"
    # I wondered if the m_compute module should pass in a parameter, but 
    # Any attempt to pass a parameter gives an error: An argument "subnet_id" is not expected here.
    #xxx = "xxx" # This fails to.
    # subnet_id = module.m_network.subnet_id
}
```

---

```
resource "aws_vpc" "myvpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

# Create subnets in each availability zone to launch our instances into, each with address blocks within the VPC:
resource "aws_subnet" "myvpc_subnet" {
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.myvpc.id}"
  cidr_block              = "10.0.1.0/24"
}
```

---

```
# Generates subnet attributes that can be passed to other modules
output "myvpc_subnet_id" {
    description = "Subnet ID"
    value = "${aws_subnet.myvpc_subnet.id}"
}
```

---

```
resource "aws_instance" "app" {
    ami           = "ami-13be557e"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    subnet_id     = aws_subnet.myvpc_subnet_id # What should go here?
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `variable "subnet_id"` block in your `./modules/compute` module? (See [Declaring an Input Variable](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#declaring-an-input-variable) for more details on the contents of such a block.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a `variables.tf` file to your `compute` module, so that it can receive the `subnet_id` from the `network` module.

Check `variables.tf` file content and the `main.tf` of the `compute` module
to see how to access the input variable.

The structure of an example should be as follows.

```
.
├── main.tf
└── modules
    ├── compute
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   └── variables.tf
    └── network
        ├── main.tf
        └── output.tf
```

Then inside each file you can do something like this.

```
# main.tf

provider "aws" {
    region     = "eu-west-1"
}

# Call network module and receive output
module "m_network" {
    source      = "./modules/network"
}

module "m_compute" {
    source     = "./modules/compute"
    # pass the output of the network module
    # as input variables for the compute module
    subnet_id  = module.m_network.output_subnet_id
}
```

```
# compute module | variables.tf

# declare a input variable for the compute module
variable "subnet_id" {
  description = "The subnet ID from the network module"

  # You can also enforce the type with
  # type = string OR number OR etc.
}
```

```
# compute module | main.tf

resource "aws_instance" "app" {
    ami           = "ami-13be557e"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    # you can use variables with var.{name}
    # access the subnet id variable
    subnet_id     = var.subnet_id
}
```

```
# network module | main.tf

resource "aws_vpc" "myvpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "myvpc_subnet" {
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.myvpc.id}"
  cidr_block              = "10.0.1.0/24"
}
```

```
# network module | output.tf

output "output_subnet_id" {
    description = "Subnet ID"
    value = "${aws_subnet.myvpc_subnet.id}"
}
```